# GitHub Pages Not Hosting Site -from Repository -> Gives 404 Error

Tags: web, github, http-status-code-404, hosting, github-pages

I have a Github repository in which I uploaded a bunch of files with code.  My little mini game runs off the index.html file predominantly.

[image]

I went to Settings to create Github Pages so I can host my game.

[image]

I am getting the following error when I click on the link:

```
404
There isn't a GitHub Pages site here.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can access to https://pinzhi000.github.io/js_flappyBird/

Comment: huh, thank you; I don't understand why that is ... I was checking that site over and over again --> is it because I have to wait awhile for the site to get hosted?

Comment: Yeah it may take some time and browser cache may be another reason.

Comment: what do you mean by browser cache?  sorry, I'm still quite new to all of this

Comment: When you try to access to a page frequently, your browser cache the page in order to open it quickly. So, you may see an older version of the page. To avoid that, you can try to use another browser, mobile phone maybe or delete the cache,